# "no match for ‘operator>>’ in ‘inputFile >> buffer" error?

Tags: c++, io, stream, segmentation-fault, operators

```
ifstream inputFile;
inputFile.open(argv[1]);
char* buffer[40];
inputFile >> buffer;
```

I also tried
    inputFile >> *buffer;
but this gives me a segmentation error.

The input txt file contains words (strings) separated by spaces. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try `char buffer[40];`

Comment: Even better, `std::string buffer;`. I, for one, don't invite you to easily run into buffer overruns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably meant array of chars:

```
char buffer[40];
inputFile >> buffer;
```